# Código no reconoce un float

Tags: python, float

Estoy aprendiendo solo programación en Python, y me puse a practicar con un programa super sencillo de calulo de impuestos. El tema es que intento que, si el usuario pone una palabra (por ejemplo), el programa le diga que tiene que ingresar un número. No logro hacer que el programa reconozca que está recibiendo números. He intentado lo siguiente:

`numero = float(int(input()))`

Sin exito.
Aqui el codigo que intento resolver.

```
    print("Ingrese un monto a calcular:")
    numero = input()
    if (type(numero) == float):                                                    
        numero = int(float(numero))
        iva = int(float(21))
        final = float((numero * int(iva) / 100) + numero)
        print('El monto total es $ ' + (str((final))))
    else:
        print('Debe escribir un numero')
```

Siempre me devuelve "Debe escribir un número", así le ponga un numero decimal o entero. Si alguien me puede ayudar, estaré agradecido.
Gracias!

Comment: Hola, numero = float(int(input())) por numero = float(input()) Asi conviertes el string que recibes del input a un flotante.

Answer (score 1):

La función `input` siempre devuelve un cadena; lo mismo que escribió el usuario en el teclado.

Para obtener un `float` o un `int` a partir de esa cadena debes ocupar las funciones de conversión `float()` o `int()`.

Sin embargo, si llamas a esas funciones con una cadena que **no** contenga un valor numérico válido, se producira la excepción `ValueError`.

La forma convencional de ingresar y validar un `float` es:

```
valor_float = None
while valor_float is None:
    valor = input("valor? ")
    try:
        valor_float = float(valor)
    except ValueError:
        print("Ingreso no es válido")

print(valor_float)
```

En general es buena práctica inicializar explícitamente las variables con `None`; así podrás saber si la variable fue correctamente inicializada (vía teclado en este caso).

El método es el mismo si quieres pedir un `int`, no un `float`:

```
valor_int = None
while valor_int is None:
    valor = input("valor? ")
    try:
        valor_int = int(valor)
    except ValueError:
        print("Ingreso no es válido")

print(valor_int)
```

Ojo, que `int()` falla si intentas convertir un float, como en `int("1.2")`

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver tu problema podemos hacer 2 observaciones:

##### `input` siempre retornara un string

Te invito a que hagas varias pruebas con lo siguiente:

```py
print(type(input()))
```

Dale cualquier entrada que quieras, y veraz que `input` siempre retornara un
string.

##### Si tratas de hacer la conversión con algo que no es un `float`, recibirás una excepción.

Corre lo siguiente:

```py
float("abc")
```

Te da el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    float("abc")
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'abc'
```

#### Una posible solución

Tomando ambas cosas en cuenta, puedes crear una función que revise si la conversión tira una excepción. Si la tira, lo que se ingreso no es un `float`.

```py
def is_float(n: str) -> bool:
    try:
        float(n)
        return True;
    except ValueError as e:
        return False

assert(is_float("3"))
assert(is_float("3.4"))
assert(not is_float(""))
assert(not is_float("Saludos"))
```